# getting an error when passing variable date from date selector into shiny app server code

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make this shiny app to get the date from the selector (ui) and pass it to the r code (server) but it is not working and outputting an error.

It seems the problem is getting input$date into the `filter` correctly.For instance if I type `filter(DATE>='2020-05-01')` it works.

Bellow is is a snippet:

```
ui <- fluidRow(box(width = 4,dateInput("date",format = "dd/mm/yyyy",language = "pt-BR", label = h3("DATE"),value = Sys.Date()))  
                             ),
                    fluidRow(box(width = 12,height = 10,plotOutput(outputId = "Plot")) 
                        ))))


server <- function(input,output){
    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
        data  %>% filter(DATE>=input$date) %>%  filter(!wday(DATE) %in% c(1,7)) %>% mutate(sdavg=rollmeanr(SALES,k=5,fill=NA)) %>% ggplot(.,aes(x=DATE)) + geom_line(aes(y=SALES,color="#003366"))+ geom_line(aes(y=sdavg,color="#ff3300"))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60),legend.position = "none")
    }) 
}
```

I get the error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): y, x when I use `filter(PEDDTEMIS>=input$date)`

What is the correct way to pass input$date to the code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by a `dateInput` is a `Date`.  The fact that your code works when you compare your data to a `character` suggests that your data contains `character`s, not `Dates`s.

The aesthetics error tells me that you have a mismatch in the lengths of your input data somewhere along the pipe.  But I can't see the filter in the code you provide.  Also, the error suggests that at this point you have only one row in your data, your line plit may not be that informative... ;)

Comment: Hi I found the solution using DATE >= as.Date(input$date) and  geom_line(stat="identity") on the pipe. It  worked. Thank you.